# JavaScript: Как сделать сообщение об ошибке рядом с полем ввода

Tags: javascript, html

Как вывести подобное окно с сообщением об ошибке с помощью JS? Сообщение на рисунке ниже выведено средствами `HTML-5`, но мне нужно настроить условие появления сообщения и его текст.

Насчёт события `onblur` в HTML-файле всё понятно; меня интересует, если ли в JS такой метод, который показывает такое по форме сообщение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё: поддаётся ли это сообщение CSS-стилизации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы изменить содержимое такого сообщения, можно воспользоваться `setCustomValidity()`:

```js
$('input').get(0).setCustomValidity('Введи Ваше имя.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >  
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Имя">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

А вот для стилизации данного сообщения, еще ничего не придумали.

Было:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper{...}
  ::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow{...}
  ::-webkit-validation-bubble{...}
  ::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-outer-arrow{...}
  ::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-inner-arrow{...}
  ::-webkit-validation-bubble-message{...}
```

но и его убрали.

Только создавать свои поля с подсказками и стилизовать их, используя возможности css,js, jquery.

Не совершенный вариант c css, но как вариант:

```css
input:required {
    border: 1px solid red; /* Красная рамка для обязательных полей */
   }

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green; /* Зеленая рамка для валидно заполненных полей */
}

form>div {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.tooltip {
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate(0%, 15%);
  top: 100%;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  will-change: opacity, visibility;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
}

.tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: -9px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid tomato;
}


input:invalid ~ .tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

input:valid ~ .tooltip {
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<form >  
  <div>
    <label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Имя">
    <span class="tooltip">Введи Ваше имя, пожалуйста!</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Идеальный ответ! Огромное Вам спасибо за время, потраченное на него!

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, нет за что!)